# Cannot read property 'signin' of undefined while testing in Jest

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, destructuring

I am using React-Native-GoogleSignIn. When i Test that in Jest it gives me an error or fetching the signIn function from my auth.js file.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'signin' of undefined

```
   9 | 
  10 | const Email = props => {
> 11 |   const {signin} = useAuth();
     |          ^
  12 |   return (
  13 |     <>
  14 |       <Header navigation={props.navigation} />

  at Component (src/containers/login/Email.js:11:10)
  at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6156:18)
  at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8690:13)
  at beginWork$$1 (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10052:16)
  at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14694:12)
  at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14667:22)
  at callback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14366:11)
  at node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2063:24
  at Scheduler_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:818:12)
  at runWithPriority (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2013:10)
```

Comment: Please post your code as well. What does your `useAuth()` function look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Email = props => {
   const signin = useAuth();    
   return (
     <>
        <Header navigation={props.navigation} />
```

use this code, may be solved your problem because error is here

**Replace**

```
const {signin} = useAuth();
```

**with**

```
const signin = useAuth();
```